# Why does my Perl program get a taint warning on one machine but not another?

Tags: perl

We have two machines in our office that we are using as web servers. Both are running Perl 5.10.0. We installed an open source ticketing system, OTRS, and on one machine it runs perfectly fine but on the other we are receiving the error

```
Insecure dependency in require while running with -T switch.
```

I'm mystified as to why having two identical Perl installs on both machines has one running fine and the other not. I am wondering if this is something at the system level maybe?
The software installs are identical. Any advice would be appreciated. 
Nikki

Comment: First place to check: Are the shebang lines identical? Second, if you are using `mod_perl`, is taint mode enabled on one `httpd.conf` or any included `.conf` files on machine and not on the other?

Comment: Whenever people say "identical" in this context, it automatically means "not identical". That you are seeing different behavior tells you that something is different, hence, not identical. :)

Comment: I would start by comparing environment variables. From the man-page, you will see that taint-mode is very sensitive to unsafe environment variables that you never normally consider.

Answer (score 1):

You can read about Perl's [taint mode](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsec.html#Taint-mode). I suspect taint mode is enabled on one machine and it is not enabled on the other.